# unable to set up spark notebook getting the no such command error and permission denied errors

Tags: spark-notebook

I am trying to run spark notebook on my machine and I followed the procedure mentioned in "**spark notebook io**". During this procedure, I am giving the command `bin/spark-notebook`, in the terminal, and I am getting

> Error: permission denied

and when I am using `sudo bin/spark-notebook` I am getting

> Error: no such command

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Changing permissions fixed the `bin/spark-notebook` command for me. Go to the folder containing the parent of the `bin` folder (I renamed mine `sparknotebook`). Then execute `chmod 755 sparknotebook` and you should be able to proceed with `cd sparknotebook` and `bin/spark-notebook` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Ricky, I changed the access permissions, but with the following command worked for me:

```
chmod +x [name of root directory of the expanded distribution]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just run

```
sudo chmod +x bin/spark-notebook
```

on my macbook air and it works